# Cast exception with RESTEasy

Tags: java, web-services, resteasy

---

I'm using `RESTEasy` to develop a simple WS client

so this my POM.XML

```
              <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
                <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1.GA</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
                <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1.GA</version>
            </dependency>
```

and this is my Test Code

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.compiere.framework.PO;
import org.compiere.model.X_I_Order;
import org.compiere.process.ProcessInfo;
import org.compiere.process.ProcessInfoParameter;
import org.compiere.process.SvrProcess;
import org.compiere.util.Ctx;
import org.compiere.util.DB;
import org.compiere.util.Trx;
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest;

import ru.compiere.report.RusReportStarter;

import com.audaxis.compiere.laserloylty.util.Carte;
import com.audaxis.compiere.laserloylty.util.IOrderRequest;
import com.audaxis.compiere.laserloylty.util.OrderHeader;
import com.audaxis.compiere.laserloylty.util.OrderLine;
import com.audaxis.compiere.model.MPInstanceProxy;

    ClientRequest request = new ClientRequest("http:/MyURL"); //Error here
```

when i try to create a new `ClientRequest` a get this Exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.jersey.impl.provider.RuntimeDelegateImpl cannot be cast to org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:351)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest.<init>(ClientRequest.java:137)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest.<init>(ClientRequest.java:132)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest.<init>(ClientRequest.java:127)
    at GetOrdersFromCardibox.getOrders(GetOrdersFromCardibox.java:109)
    at GetOrdersFromCardibox.main(GetOrdersFromCardibox.java:226)
```

Can any one tell me where's the problem ?!

Comment: It looks like you've got a conflict in your imports and you've somehow got 2 different ClientRequest classes there and based on the signature it's picking the wrong one. What are all your imports?

Comment: i edit my post and add all my imports

Comment: Which server are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest in a current version, you can see that it is deprecated with the following comment:

> The Resteasy client framework in resteasy-jaxrs is replaced by the
>   JAX-RS 2.0 compliant resteasy-client module.

So you should consider to use the Jax-RS Client API with RestEasy as provider. For some documentation look at:
http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.16.Final/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html#d4e2141

The documentation contains the following example-code:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        ... or...
Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().build();
WebTarget target = client.target("http://foo.com/resource");
Response response = target.request().get();
String value = response.readEntity(String.class);
response.close();  // You should close connections!
```

You might need to update your dependencies to a newer version of RestEasy. You can find some help here:
http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.16.Final/userguide/html/Maven_and_RESTEasy.html

Core libraries are:

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.16.Final</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.16.Final</version>
   </dependency>
```