# Use RestEasy Client in a service built with DropWizard

Tags: jakarta-ee, jersey, resteasy, dropwizard

As the title suggest, I have a Service built with DropWizard (and hence Jersey). Within this service I have to make calls to another service built with RestEasy using RestEasy client. Problem is as soon as I add the dependency to RestEasy client in my service, I run into problems with creating the proxy. Basically I get the following trace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.glassfish.jersey.uri.internal.JerseyUriBuilder cannot be cast to org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.ResteasyUriBuilder
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientWebTarget.queryParamNoTemplate(ClientWebTarget.java:289)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.processors.webtarget.QueryParamProcessor.apply(QueryParamProcessor.java:23)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.processors.webtarget.QueryParamProcessor.apply(QueryParamProcessor.java:12)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.processors.AbstractCollectionProcessor.buildIt(AbstractCollectionProcessor.java:76)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.processors.webtarget.AbstractWebTargetCollectionProcessor.build(AbstractWebTargetCollectionProcessor.java:22)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.createRequest(ClientInvoker.java:115)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:101)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:64)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy68.disableAccounts(Unknown Source)
```

To build the RestEasy client:

```
ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(uri);
target.proxy(AccountResource.class);
```

"AccountResource" being the contract interface.

Searching around (i.e.: [Cast exception with RESTEasy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36550057/cast-exception-with-resteasy)) and debugging the code tells me that this is a classpath issue. I wonder if there is a way to achieve this with RestEasy client, basically telling the client which URI builder to use.

Comment: Just an aside, but you know Jersey has a client proxy also. Just because the server is built with RESTEasy, you don't need to use the RESTEasy client. The Jersey client works the same way, using the JAX-RS resource interfaces.

Comment: Very True. I was just hoping to use an existing code from elsewhere. If I can't, that would be my fallback plan. Thanks.

Comment: Most likely what is happening is that the RESTEasy client is using the standard JAX-RS `ClientBuilder`, which is implemented to first look for the Jersey Client builder. Then it will go to any other on the class path